# C# - Need Help Understanding the Lambda Operation and <T>

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm currently working on a project, and need a method to get me a variable's name. (XmlNode type). I found this solution - but I have no clue how it works. Any explanation would be helpful. Thank you!

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    GetName(new { var1 });
    GetName2(() => var1);
}

static string GetName<T>(T item) where T : class 
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
}

static string GetName2<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr) 
{
    return ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

In particular, I don't understand why the parameter is `(new {var1})` and `(() => var1)` when calling the methods, what `<T>(T item) where T : class` means, and what `<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)` means.

I did read about the lambda operation and `<T>`, but that doesn't really help that much.

Comment: For the whole <T> part of the question, read about [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: The best part is that none of those methods will get you a variable's name.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just ran the code, after defining the var1 myself and got it.

Comment: @Fabulous: initialising var1=0 in the first call works too & I agree that they do get the name.

Comment: The first method gives you the name of a property defined in an anonymous object, the second method gives you the name of the member of the expression tree. So, in both cases you need to wrap the variable to get its name, hence, they don't give you the name of a variable.

Comment: `nameof(var1)` returns `var1`

Answer (score 1):

First, the `nameof` operator was introduced in, I believe, c# 6. It can do what you want. You use it like this:

```
var myVariable = new Object();
var myVariableName = nameof(myVariable);
```

Now to unpack your question.

**What is `(new {var1})`?**

Here you are calling the `GetName` method. That method takes a single parameter. The object being passed to the method in this case is instantiated with this code: `new { var1 }`. Here `new { var1 }` is creating an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). The object being created has a single property named 'var1' whose value is the variable `var1`. Because a property name was not supplied the property was automatically given the same name as the variable. You could have explicitly named the property when you declared the anonymous type like this: `new { var1 = var1 }`. Or you could have given your property a completely different name: `new { DifferentName = var1 }` (but this would cause `GetName` to return the wrong result - see below). If you were to explicitly define these types as classes they would look something like these, respectively:

```
public class  MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass(T property)
    {
        var1 = property;
    }
    public var1 { get; }
}
```

and this:

```
public class  MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass(T property)
    {
        DifferentName = property;
    }
    public DifferentName { get; }
}
```

**What is `<T>(T item) where T : class`?**

The `<T>` in `GetName<T>` or `GetName2<T>` is a generic type parameter ([generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)). In this case it allows you to delay the type specification of the method parameter until the method is invoked. So if I had a method with this signature, for example, `MyMethod<T>(T item)` I could later call it with an int like this `MyMethod<int>(2)` or a string like this `MyMethod<string>('some string')`. Here I am explicitly specifying the type with `<int>` and `<string>`. In many cases, when the type is unambigous, you can exclude the type declaration and C# will infer it. So I could do this `MyMethod('some string')` and C# will be able to infer the type is `string`. That is what is happening here: `GetName(new { var1 })`. Since `new { var1 }` is an anonymous type there is no way to explicitly specify the type when calling `GetName`. But you can still call `GetName` with an anonymous type simply by allowing C# to infer the type.

The `where T : class` portion of the method signature is just a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), i.e. a constraint is being placed on the types that can be passed to this method. In this case the constraint is that `T` must be a `class` and not a value type.

**How does `GetName<T>` work?**

This function is using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to inspect the object that was passed to it. Here is what is going on: `typeof(T)` gets the type of object that was passed (remember we are passing an anonymous type), `GetProperties()` gets all the properties of the type - this will give you an array of `PropertyInfo`, `[0]` gives you the first property in that array (in the case where `new { var1 }` is passed to this method the object will only have a single property named 'var1'), and finally `Name` gives you the name of that property.

This method is making assumptions about the object being passed to it. Specifically that the object passed has at least 1 property and that the name of the the first property has the same name as the variable whose name we are interested in. This method is far from foolproof, it could easily be broken at runtime by passing an object with no properties, or you could get back the wrong name if you failed to pass an object that conformed to the assumptions that `GetName` is making.

Interestingly, `GetName` could have been implemented without generics like this:

```
static string GetName3(object item)
{
    return item.GetType().GetProperties()[0].Name;
}
```

Perhaps the author was attempting to take advantage of at least a tiny bit of compile time checking by eliminating an entire class of objects (value types) that have no properties from being passed to the method.

**What is `(() => var1)`?**

This is an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions). This particular expression represents a function that takes no parameters `()` and returns an object. I know that from the method signature of `GetName2`:

```
GetName2<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)`
```

See, the `expr` parameter is an `Expression` of type `Func` (a function) that takes no parameters and returns a on object of type `T`.

**How does `GetName2<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)` work?**

Well... the short and probably not very accurate answer is that it is returning the right side of the expression. So you pass in `() => var1` and you get back `var1`. Let's just leave it at that for now.

Answer (score -1):

- `new {var1}` creates an anonymous object
- `(() => var1)` is a lambda function with no parameters shorthand for:
  `delegate void () { return var1;}`
- `<T>(T item) where T : class`  is reflection and constraining the generic 
     parameter to a class. See DarkSquirrel42 answer

Comment: `delegate void () { return var1;}` is not a valid syntax for creating a delegate, or an anonymous method.  Additionally, the lambda in question *is not creating a delegate*, it's creating an Expression object.  A generic constraint isn't using reflection.  The method that has a generic constraint happens to use reflection within it, but that's very different.